# loading page issue with these php code

Tags: php

I'm getting issue on the server when i upload my webpage, doesn't load because of the connection file to database, here is the code that i use on local server xampp, but on cpanel/webserver doesn't work. I need help.

```
 <?php
        error_reporting(0);
            // 1. Create a database connection

            $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","eparktec_mwakale1","AqTtl7qFBuJ4");
            if (!$connection) {
                die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
            }

            // 2. Select a database to use 
            $db_select = mysql_select_db("eparktec_mwakale",$connection);
            if (! $db_select) {
                die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: How specifically is it failing?  What's the error?

Comment: maybe your server have php7 and does not have. `mysql_*`

Comment: is your `cpanel` hots `localhost` ?. when u are on phpmyadmin from your cpanel does it say localhost

Comment: use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`

Comment: I think the issue it could on the select code, because when i remove the line of code $db_select = mysql_select_db("eparktec_mwakale",$connection);
            if (! $db_select) {
                die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
            }

Comment: It says "This page isn’t working mydomain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500, I want a user to select a location before login to the system, so system checks if the user registered on that location

Comment: when you deploy on a host usually are provided with the url to the mysql instance(s) for the host. the localhost parameter in the mysql_connect call is quite sure wrong. correct it with a proper DSN and retry.

Comment: What are the proper code on mysqli connect and select db, because i want to connect to the database, and the sametime select the db name, the code above works proper on local server xampp, but when i upload on cpanel, doesn't work. it blocks the webpage from running. I need help to re-correct the code above.

Comment: @JohnMaximize did you check the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The might be two problems with your connection code. 1. The live server on cpanel/webserver might be using a php version that does not support the `mysql_*` functions that you are using, they are depreciated and no longer used, in the newer php version, better use mysqli or pdo.

1. The host might be incorrect? check the host,username and password are correct.

When you are on cpanel you can login to phpmyadmin from there once login you may see, the host/server name : its wtitten `server:whatever` make sure on your communication you write that server name screenshot shows how to see the server name from phpmyadmin of a live server, from your cpanel.

[image]

Phpmyadmin is available once you are in your cpanel dashboard under databases.

use `mysqli_*` to connect not `mysql_*`

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "eparktec_mwakale1";
$password = "AqTtl7qFBuJ4";
$dbname = "eparktec_mwakale";

// Create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$connection) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```